# did not match expected type spring framework error

Tags: java, spring

I have a service built on spring framework 
i am wondering why I have this exception though I am sending an integer to my service

> ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-13) UT005023: Exception
>   handling request to /updateUserAnswer/11:
>   org.lightadmin.core.view.exceptions.BadRequestException:
>   org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [11] did not match
>   expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]

here is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateUserAnswers/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public Response updateUserAnswer(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId,
            @RequestBody @Valid UserAnswer userAnswer) {

        userAnswerService.updateUserAnswer(userId, userAnswer);

        HashMap<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("messages", null);
        response.put("success", Boolean.valueOf(true));
        return Response.instance().friendlyName("user-answer-updated").object(response).statusCode(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

here is my service :

```
public void updateUserAnswer(Long userId,UserAnswer userAnswer) {

    List<UserAnswer> currentUserAnswer = userAnswerRepo.getUserAnswers(userId, userAnswer.getAnswerId().longValue(),null);
    currentUserAnswer.get(0).setLabel(userAnswer.getLabel());       

    List<UserAnswerField> fieldsList =  new ArrayList<UserAnswerField>();


    for (UserAnswerField userAnswerField : userAnswer.getAnswerFields()) {
        UserAnswerField currentUserAnswerField = userAnswerFieldRepo.getUserAnswerField(userAnswerField.getfieldId());
        if (currentUserAnswerField != null) {
            currentUserAnswerField.setfield(userAnswerField.getfield());
            currentUserAnswerField.setTypeId(userAnswerField.getTypeId());
            fieldsList.add(currentUserAnswerField);
            //userAnswerFieldRepo.save(currentUserAnswerField);
        }           
    }   
    currentUserAnswer.get(0).setAnswerFields(fieldsList);

    userAnswerRepo.save(currentUserAnswer.get(0));
}
```

repository :

```
public List<UserAnswer> getUserAnswers(Long userId,Long answerId ,String pageType) {
    try {
        String qlString = ""
                + " Select sf from UserAnswer sf "
                + " where "
                + " sf.userId = :userId ";
        if(pageType != null){
            qlString+= " and  sf.type=:type ";
        }
        if(answerId != null){
            qlString+= " and sf.answerId=:answerId ";
        }
        qlString+=" order by sf.insertionDate";

        Query query = getEntityManagerFactory().createQuery(qlString);
        query.setParameter("userId", userId);
        if(pageType != null){
            query.setParameter("type", pageType);
        }
        if(answerId != null){
            query.setParameter("answerId", answerId);
        }
        return (List<UserAnswer>) query.getResultList();
    } catch (javax.persistence.NoResultException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

can you help me out ? thanks in advance

Comment: Please show you URL.

Comment: Why expected type is Integer when the method requires Long?

Comment: @StanislavL i edited my question and added service code , i think that is where the error is happening

Comment: What happens if you change to Integer in the controller updateUserAnswer(@PathVariable("userId") Integer userId,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens at `query.setParameter("userId", userId);` because you're trying to set a Long when hqlQuery is expecting an Integer.

Solutions :

- Change type `Long` -> `Integer` from controller to Repository
- Use `.intValue()` (more a quick fix than a solution)
- Change ids in your entities to Long type.

Comment: `UserAnswer.answerId` type is Integer or Long (in your Entity) ?

`UserAnswer.userId type` is Integer or Long (in your Entity) ?

Comment: in entity they both are int ,, the error is happening at exactly this line : query.setParameter("userId", userId); @Daminox

Answer (score 0):

You get an exception because you need to bind a primitive type.

Try this :

```
 public Response updateUserAnswer(@PathVariable("userId") long userId,
             @RequestBody @Valid UserAnswer userAnswer) { [...] }
```

Comment: i think the error is happening at service layer , i edited the question and added it

Comment: I would be surprised. The exception is explecit. The parameter does not match with what it is expected. Put a debug breakpoint just before the call of your service. I think your code will never stop.

Comment: i added a print and it does reach the service , so no issue with controller

Comment: Do you know where exactly your Service throw the exception ? I think it is possible that a function in your service expect an Integer as parameter but you give a Long .

Comment: okay so the error is happening at this line :      List<UserAnswer> currentUserAnswer = userAnswerRepo.getUserAnswers(answerId, userAnswer.getAnswerId().longValue(),null);

Comment: Well, you need to debug getUserAnswers function now. Where is the expcetion thrown in the function ?